# When casting Bend or Break, who and when chooses the opponents?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-multiplayer

When casting [Bend or Break](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Bend%20or%20Break), who and when chooses the opponents? Should they be chosen on cast or resolution? Must each opponent be different? Can the caster be the opponent of each of the opponents? Does the caster choose the opponents for each opponent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the official Oracle wording, instead of the outdated printed wording, it becomes clearer:

> Each player separates all nontoken lands they control into two piles. For each player, one of their piles is chosen **by one of their opponents of their choice**. Destroy all lands in the chosen piles. Tap all lands in the other piles.

So each player who is having their nontoken lands separated chooses an opponent of their choice.

The choice is made on resolution. The only choices made when casting a spell are the targets and modes. Everything else is chosen on resolution.

Comment: Is there an other for players to pick their opponents in? I'm imagining "Hey, Player A, I'll go easy on you if you go easy on me." "OK." *both players lose only one land*

Comment: @nick012000 608.2e says each player will divide their cards in APNAP order, then each player in APNAP order will have a pile chosen (which involves them choosing an opponent).

Comment: I don’t know if there are general rules about table talk or deal-making in multiplayer games.

Comment: The comprehensive rules don't say anything about player communication. The tournament rules do, but they only apply to tournaments, which don't involve multiplayer games, and they also do not disallow or discourage those kinds of interactions. Anecdotally, "politics" is commonly considered an integral part of multiplayer MTG.